Is it correct to tilt the pole of a GPS / GNSS antenna to procure the position?
Recently a salesperson from a company that sells GPS / GNSS equipment visited our college to demonstrate the GPS / GNSS device in a differential mode. The salesperson was demonstrating a GNSS antenna pair for differential surveying.
While demonstrating, the person took the antenna mounted on a pole near a building, then tilted the pole saying that he was trying to procure a position, and then made it straight.
By surveying standards, is it ok to tilt the pole? Also, by surveying standards, is it ok to take the antenna close to a building, even if it is for differential positioning?

+L5 has made GPS fixes easier near or around buildings/trees. The lower frequency range of the L5 GPS band gives signals transmitted at these frequencies better propagation and penetrating properties over those sent in via L1/L2 bands, thereby enhancing the quality of reception.

As with a lot of things, the answer is going to be "it depends". When using an RTK setup with paired GNSS base and rover units that are communicating via a radio link, there are multiple reasons you might have trouble taking points next to a building, trees, or other obstacles.
Most commonly either 1. the rover lost radio link with the base because its signal has been blocked or 2. the rover can't see enough satellites because too much of the horizon is blocked.
Tilting the pole temporarily for the rover antenna can sometimes help reestablish the radio link with the base unit, but you still need to return the pole to vertical before you collect points or you will not have accurate coordinates.
However, tilting the pole isn't going help the rover unit see any more satellites if the building, tree, or other obstacle it is next to is blocking too much of the horizon-- the pole needs to be vertical while you collect points to avoid introducing a horizontal offset that gives you inaccurate results. Generally, we aim to have less than 15% of the horizon blocked, but that is not always possible in every case depending on what you need to shoot in.
Bottom line-- tilting the pole temporarily may help in some limited circumstances, but you should always have the pole vertical while actually collecting coordinates with the rover.

There are two aspects in this question, i.e. measuring with a tilted pole and measuring close to buildings.
Measuring with a tilted pole is a function which has been introduced by GNSS manufacturers in the last 5 or 10 years.  Here's a very good article from GPS World which describes this.  So basically, with modern equipment, taking GNSS measurements with a tilted pole is normal practice these days.
The second aspect, working near buildings, has seen similar improvements.  I've been working with GNSS equipment (mostly Trimble) for about 15 years. Using a GPS-only device like GeoExplorer 2008 under canopy or near buildings was a waste of time - it often wouldn't give any positions, if it did give positions they were often hugely inaccurate.  The next generation (GeoExplorer 6000) added GLONASS to GPS, so the number of satellites almost doubled and the GNSS processing also improved.  Geo6000 usually gave positions under canopy or near buildings, but accuracy was often "not great".  Then Geo 7x added Beidou, Galileo, and QZSS so even more satellites were available.  The traditional surveying lessons about not obscuring sky view have become less important since they were partly based on seeing some minimum number of satellites.
Fast forward to receivers like Trimble R12i (presumably Topcon and Leica and other manufacturers have made similar advances) - in comparison, these are amazing.  The GNSS side is improved in sensitivity and number of satellites, and the addition of built-in Inertial Measurement components mean that the GNSS (actually a system, not just a GNSS) really works well in harsh conditions.   Sorry, I couldn't find an article on these harsh-environment improvements.
